# I can't authenticate or log in any user account in Laravel Application every several hours, why?

Tags: authentication, laravel

In my Laravel application, after a user is logged for the first time after registration using

```
loginUsingId()
```

the user gets authenticated (logged in). But after a few hours (maybe 2-3 hours. I'm not sure), after the session has expired or the user has logged out, it can't log in back again using:

```
Auth::attempt()
```

But it happens for a reason that I don't know. Why is this happening? Please share your expertise on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most probably, you are not storing the registration data perfectly in the DB.
   Is the password hashed perfectly?)
2. Or cipher proble. Help [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.2).
3. Or rememberToken methods are not set up perfectly. Help [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26).